# MTM/VSTS Query for two-level hierarchy work items

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

It would be great if i can get a query in MTM/VSTS to pull out testing metrics with the below hierarchy:

Test suite(ID: 1) -> Test cases (ID: 11,12,13,14) -> Shared steps/Bugs(ID: 21,  22)

As of now i am using two different queries to achieve this. (one for extracting Test cases from Test suite and another for extracting Shared steps/bugs from Test case.) I need a single query for this so that i have single report as below:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with Work Item Visualization extension?

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much for your suggestion. It was helpful. And, further could you please help me in understanding whether this can be downloaded in order to share with Management team. I can see an option to save it within VSTS, but i am looking to download this visualization. Thanks is advance again.

Comment: Based on the document of that extension, it has export feature, but it isn't, you can send the email (bottom of the document) for support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t do it through the Query directly. There is a [Work Item Visualization extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.WorkItemVisualization) that can do it.

Simple steps:

1. Run a query (e.g. Work Items and direct links) to get related test suites
2. Right click these test suites=> Visualize

[image]